# Passenger Records Research for Pakistan

Tags: immigration, records, india, pakistan

I am looking for passenger records for an ancestor who is rumoured to have run because he **murdered** someone in his **homeland**.

I am trying to research him. I have asked my family members who are currently living, but they do not have much, if any, information about him.

He was born in the **1800s +/- 40 years** in **Peshawar, Pakistan**. This was before the **British colonisation** of India. When he ran, he came to **Mumbai(formerly known as Bombay), India.**

Where can I find passenger records for **native Pakistanis** who **immigrated** **from Peshawar, Pakistan**, to **Mumbai(formerly known as Bombay), India**, in the **1800's +/- 30 years**?

Answer (score 2):

There may not be any passenger lists for that route or that general type of journey.
In general, lists were created for the benefit of the immigration authorities at the place of arrival. They mostly only exist for intercontinental journeys like England to America or Australia. I have never seen any for shorter journeys like Pakistan to India (all of which was the same country/jurisdiction then). Under British rule it was a domestic journey and that presumably means that there may not have been any arrivals checks. So no passenger list required.

Comment: Okay, thank you for the answer.
Is there any place that I can look for domestic journey records for these countries online?
Would it be better for me to research in Pakistan or India?

Comment: Yes that’s a possibility but I wonder precisely what records may still exist, after 170 years or more. I doubt births were registered there in 1830 (that didn’t start in England till 1837).

Answer (score 2):

The term "Pakistan" is an anachronism for that time. So far as I can see, Peshawar was part of the Sikh Empire until the Empire was defeated by the British in 1849. Even so, I can find no indication that passenger lists were kept in that era for traffic between the Sikh Empire and the Bombay Presidency of the East India Company (to use the contemporary names). (It's important to know the contemporary names because that's how stuff gets written down and catalogued in the records).

Any references that I have found refer mostly to travel between South Asia and Europe - where passenger lists were kept for journeys to or from the UK. There are also mentions of passengers arriving or departing on coastal shipping in the South Asia area but these appear to be basically news items so it's no surprise that the only examples I saw quoted were European passengers.

Given that the British didn't bother to keep passenger records of shipping between the UK and Continental Europe, I wouldn't hold out any hopes for coastal shipping around South Asia.